# using sums in SELECT subquery with where clause and group by

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I am trying to accomplish something like the following pseudocode:

```
SELECT category, subcategory, 
    SUM(value WHERE type = A) as sumA, 
    SUM(value WHERE type = B) as sumB
FROM table 
GROUP BY category, subcategory
```

There are some category-subcategory combos that only have either Type A or Type B, and I want the other to read as `null` in the resulting table.

I want the final table to look like this:

| category | subcategory | sumA | sumB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | value | null |
| C | D | value | value |

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation ; the syntax is pretty close to your pseudo-code:

```
select category, subcategory,
    sum(case when type = 'A' then val end) as sumA,
    sum(case when type = 'B' then val end) as sumB
from mytable
group by category, subcategory
```

> There are some category-subcategory combos that only have either Type A or Type B, and I want the other to read as `null` in the resulting table.

When there is no row for a given `type` in a category/subcategory tuple, the `sum` returns `null`, as you expect.